# mbr and boot sector overwritten with structured yet very odd data

Tags: boot, mbr, overwrite

I work for a web-hosting datacenter.  One server was having issues with its RAID, and we were attempting to reboot into single-user mode to repair a read-only /tmp

Upon rebooting, the server wouldn't come up, stating no boot disk.  This seemed improbable because the box was just up a minute prior.

1 SysRescueCD boot later, I examined the partition table with fdisk: there was none. 
I then examined the array with `less -f /dev/sda`  and saw...very strange things.  Unlike any bootsector I had ever seen.

I copied it to the boot usb... Then promptly restored a backup of the boot/mbr from our backup system.  The server reboots again as normal, and all partitions match with what our backup system had.

But I want to know: WHAT in all the good world would have caused this.

Taken from the disk, with 
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/usbstick/filename bs=1M count=1`

The first 0x00001000 bytes are.. interesting..

Anyone seen anything like this before?

```
0000000: 0296 0008 6861 6e67 6f76 6572 3f8a 8a67  ....hangover?..g
0000010: 0000 0479 ea58 8000 3f3f f9db 0000 05d7  ...y.X..??......
0000020: 9744 8000 3f28 e7f1 0000 05f2 4fcc 8008  .D..?(......O...
0000030: 01e2 3f5e b49d 0000 0455 81d4 8008 0173  ..?^.....U.....s
0000040: 3f52 18f8 0000 045c 8c50 8004 0472 6169  ?R.....\.P...rai
0000050: 6c3f 35ed 7f00 0004 ab08 d480 0401 733f  l?5...........s?
0000060: 2377 e700 0000 772d 2080 003f 4c3b 4500  #w....w- ..?L;E.
0000070: 0000 a2f5 8480 003f 10cc 5500 0000 c0fa  .......?..U.....
0000080: c480 003f 4dbf 5100 0000 ec62 7c80 003f  ...?M.Q....b|..?
0000090: 46f9 eb00 0000 eece 8080 003f 3c63 7300  F..........?<cs.
00000a0: 0001 0fd6 ac80 003f 2434 8b00 0001 6213  .......?$4....b.
00000b0: 4880 003f 4c4f 4600 0004 0984 5880 003f  H..?LOF.....X..?
00000c0: 34a4 8d00 0005 1513 b080 003f 18c7 3800  4..........?..8.
00000d0: 0005 91b5 cc80 003f 3a09 4600 0006 0b08  .......?:.F.....
00000e0: 3880 003f 5218 2900 0006 4a3b 0880 0502  8..?R.)...J;....
00000f0: 5353 3f4d bf51 0000 010d 6874 8004 0375  SS?M.Q....ht...u
0000100: 7073 3f45 131e 0000 037a 300c 8004 0277  ps?E.....z0....w
0000110: 613f 5218 f800 0002 77a2 6480 0404 7a68  a?R.....w.d...zh
0000120: 6f75 3f2e 60a7 0000 004f 375c 8000 3f2e  ou?.`....O7\..?.
0000130: 60a7 0000 00b5 9534 8000 3f4f 3d01 0000  `......4..?O=...
0000140: 05e2 61ec 8003 0168 3f28 6cdd 0000 027c  ..a....h?(l....|
0000150: 81b4 8003 0269 633f 41a5 6000 0006 3e03  .....ic?A.`...>.
0000160: 9080 0402 656c 3f23 c3c0 0000 0585 b708  ....el?#........
0000170: 8003 016b 3f3f f50a 0000 0501 1b20 8000  ...k??....... ..
0000180: 3ef5 b7d8 0000 0581 eed4 8000 3f1d 0096  >...........?...
0000190: 0000 0592 99a4 8000 3f33 5d39 0000 05e2  ........?3]9....
00001a0: 9d78 8004 0265 723f 3ecc 4500 0004 69a9  .x...er?>.E...i.
00001b0: cc80 0603 696e 673f 15bb 8900 0005 1152  ....ing?.......R
00001c0: 3c80 003f 3897 f200 0005 5df8 4880 0405  <..?8.....].H...
00001d0: 6675 6c6c 793f 3e55 a700 0004 93c4 bc80  fully?>U........
00001e0: 0401 733f 4ab3 1900 0000 4730 b480 003f  ..s?J.....G0...?
00001f0: 4611 b400 0004 0321 d480 003f 48a0 8000  F......!...?H...
0000200: 0004 5c4b 7880 003f 2b2c 3700 0004 9b6f  ..\Kx..?+,7....o
0000210: bc80 003f 06c7 7600 0004 ca45 5880 003f  ...?..v....EX..?
0000220: 4513 1e00 0005 4b03 e880 003f 1bf0 e200  E.....K....?....
0000230: 0005 bdf4 e080 0401 793f 3897 f200 0005  ........y?8.....
0000240: 4e44 d080 003f 33e1 f800 0006 56ac 9480  ND...?3.....V...
0000250: 0303 6c65 793f 479d 1000 0004 0825 dc80  ..ley?G......%..
0000260: 003f 30db 8b00 0005 4a51 a880 0402 6f6e  .?0.....JQ....on
0000270: 3f16 247d 0000 05a9 71fc 8003 01d1 3f3f  ?.$}....q.....??
0000280: f9db 0000 02f5 8d90 8004 0161 3f60 f4c1  ...........a?`..
0000290: 0000 00b6 5184 0161 3f60 f4c1 0000 00b6  ....Q..a?`......
00002a0: 5184 0161 3f60 f4c1 0000 00b6 5184 0401  Q..a?`......Q...
00002b0: 613f 60f4 c100 0000 b651 8401 613f 60f4  a?`......Q..a?`.
00002c0: c100 0000 b651 846c 0006 ba55 0000 0586  .....Q.l...U....
00002d0: de9c 0006 ba56 0000 0586 e1e4 0006 ba57  .....V.........W
00002e0: 0000 0586 e674 0006 b9f2 0000 0585 c9f8  .....t..........
00002f0: 0006 b9f3 0000 0585 cc1c 0006 b9f4 0000  ................
0000300: 0585 cd90 0006 b9f5 0000 0585 d0e0 0006  ................
0000310: b9f6 0000 0585 d528 0006 b9f7 0000 0585  .......(........
0000320: d888 0006 b9f8 0000 0585 ddb8 0006 b9f9  ................
0000330: 0000 0585 e0d8 0006 b9fa 0000 0585 e3b8  ................
0000340: 0006 b9fb 0000 0585 e654 0006 b9fc 0000  .........T......
0000350: 0585 e7f4 0006 b9fd 0000 0585 ea40 0006  .............@..
0000360: b9fe 0000 0585 ed28 0006 b9ff 0000 0585  .......(........
0000370: ee34 0006 ba00 0000 0585 f008 0006 ba01  .4..............
0000380: 0000 0585 f458 0006 ba02 0000 0585 f1ac  .....X..........
0000390: 0006 ba03 0000 0585 f6a4 0006 ba04 0000  ................
00003a0: 0585 fa10 0006 ba05 0000 0585 fda8 0006  ................
00003b0: ba06 0000 0586 0120 0006 ba07 0000 0586  ....... ........
00003c0: 03c8 0006 ba08 0000 0586 0614 0006 ba09  ................
00003d0: 0000 0586 0808 0006 ba0a 0000 0586 0c34  ...............4
00003e0: 0006 ba0b 0000 0586 0e70 0006 ba0c 0000  .........p......
00003f0: 0586 1138 0006 ba0d 0000 0586 12e8 53e8  ...8..........S.
0000400: 0260 000c 6c79 6f71 7155 7566 6359 7847  .`..lyoqqUufcYxG
0000410: 3f3d 5e78 0000 011f 92d8 8002 0551 5441  ?=^x.........QTA
0000420: 4e70 3f27 c7c6 0000 0116 3878 8002 0372  Np?'......8x...r
0000430: 6361 3f31 5bad 0000 03ea ac2c 8000 3f41  ca?1[......,..?A
0000440: 7886 0000 0416 4a30 8003 0369 616e 3f3f  x.....J0...ian??
0000450: f9db 0000 03f4 be30 8004 0163 3f56 22e7  .......0...c?V".
0000460: 0000 00b3 2a24 8000 3f3f 5903 0000 00fc  ....*$..??Y.....
0000470: 3998 8000 3f37 571f 0000 01e3 9878 8000  9...?7W......x..
0000480: 3f31 dfb0 0000 054b f7dc 8000 3f31 dfb0  ?1.....K....?1..
0000490: 0000 05ce 8c68 8000 3f31 dfb0 0000 05fa  .....h..?1......
00004a0: a654 8000 3f31 dfb0 0000 0636 c22c 8005  .T..?1.....6.,..
00004b0: 0161 3f5a 563e 0000 02dc 6fd8 8000 3f14  .a?ZV>....o...?.
00004c0: 5f2e 0000 05b3 8d8c 8006 016c 3f50 214d  _..........l?P!M
00004d0: 0000 0626 caa4 8005 0369 736d 3f23 55dd  ...&.....ism?#U.
00004e0: 0000 0586 e98c 8007 0174 3f23 a60f 0000  .........t?#....
00004f0: 0479 ea58 8000 3f27 6e00 0000 05a8 d424  .y.X..?'n......$
0000500: 8000 3f50 214d 0000 05b5 57cc 8000 3f54  ..?P!M....W...?T
0000510: 189a 0000 05e7 4b58 8008 0173 3f3e 74b5  ......KX...s?>t.
0000520: 0000 0568 9070 8005 0173 3f57 665a 0000  ...h.p...s?WfZ..
0000530: 000e 3b9c 8000 3f2c 1a53 0000 0012 8ef8  ..;...?,.S......
0000540: 8000 3f12 9027 0000 0072 c7f8 8000 3f1f  ..?..'...r....?.
0000550: 2393 0000 0078 c9e0 8000 3f21 efc9 0000  #....x....?!....
0000560: 007d ce20 8000 3f3c 6373 0000 007f 64a8  .}. ..?<cs....d.
0000570: 8000 3f6a 6ea7 0000 0098 e0d0 8000 3fa5  ..?jn.........?.
0000580: b2e1 0000 00b6 af24 8000 3f4e 33c2 0000  .......$..?N3...
0000590: 00b8 34c4 8000 3f41 a560 0000 00bc e2cc  ..4...?A.`......
00005a0: 8000 3ef9 ea26 0000 00c0 7d7c 8000 3f3f  ..>..&....}|..??
00005b0: f9db 0000 00d2 ef68 8000 3f52 1829 0000  .......h..?R.)..
00005c0: 00d9 05fc 8000 3f45 131e 0000 00d9 0f74  ......?E.......t
00005d0: 8000 3f38 1bfc 0000 00de bc0c 8000 3f46  ..?8..........?F
00005e0: 11b4 0000 00e8 1978 8000 3f3b 1948 0000  .......x..?;.H..
00005f0: 00eb e814 8000 3f50 214d 0000 00f6 32e0  ......?P!M....2.
0000600: 8000 3f3f f9db 0000 00fb b860 8000 3f4f  ..??.......`..?O
0000610: 3d01 0000 0100 96a4 8000 3f36 b626 0000  =.........?6.&..
0000620: 011e 0c34 8000 3eec 4d04 0000 0122 649c  ...4..>.M...."d.
0000630: 8000 3f1f 0b98 0000 012f 52f0 8000 3ee0  ..?....../R...>.
0000640: 1003 0000 013e b660 8000 3f2a b5a2 0000  .....>.`..?*....
0000650: 0198 0f0c 8000 3f3a d3dc 0000 01c0 98f4  ......?:........
0000660: 8000 3f3a d3dc 0000 01c0 98f4 8000 3f3a  ..?:..........?:
0000670: d3dc 0000 01c0 98f4 0006 ba4d 0000 0586  ...........M....
0000680: c858 0006 ba4e 0000 0586 cad4 0006 ba4f  .X...N.........O
0000690: 0000 0586 cf08 0006 ba50 0000 0586 d240  .........P.....@
00006a0: 0006 ba51 0000 0586 d48c 0006 ba52 0000  ...Q.........R..
00006b0: 0586 d6bc 0006 ba53 0000 0586 da3c 0006  .......S.....<..
00006c0: ba54 0000 0586 dc6c 0006 ba55 0000 0586  .T.....l...U....
00006d0: de9c 0006 ba56 0000 0586 e1e4 0006 ba57  .....V.........W
00006e0: 0000 0586 e674 0006 b9f2 0000 0585 c9f8  .....t..........
00006f0: 0006 b9f3 0000 0585 cc1c 0006 b9f4 0000  ................
0000700: 0585 cd90 0006 b9f5 0000 0585 d0e0 0006  ................
0000710: b9f6 0000 0585 d528 0006 b9f7 0000 0585  .......(........
0000720: d888 0006 b9f8 0000 0585 ddb8 0006 b9f9  ................
0000730: 0000 0585 e0d8 0006 b9fa 0000 0585 e3b8  ................
0000740: 0006 b9fb 0000 0585 e654 0006 b9fc 0000  .........T......
0000750: 0585 e7f4 0006 b9fd 0000 0585 ea40 0006  .............@..
0000760: b9fe 0000 0585 ed28 0006 b9ff 0000 0585  .......(........
0000770: ee34 0006 ba00 0000 0585 f008 0006 ba01  .4..............
0000780: 0000 0585 f458 0006 ba02 0000 0585 f1ac  .....X..........
0000790: 0006 ba03 0000 0585 f6a4 0006 ba04 0000  ................
00007a0: 0585 fa10 0006 ba05 0000 0585 fda8 0006  ................
00007b0: ba06 0000 0586 0120 0006 ba07 0000 0586  ....... ........
00007c0: 03c8 0006 ba08 0000 0586 0614 0006 ba09  ................
00007d0: 0000 0586 0808 0006 ba0a 0000 0586 0c34  ...............4
00007e0: 0006 ba0b 0000 0586 0e70 0006 ba0c 0000  .........p......
00007f0: 0586 1138 0006 ba0d 0000 0586 12e8 53e8  ...8..........S.
0000800: 026f 0004 7374 6174 3f42 a385 0000 03ab  .o..stat?B......
0000810: cad8 8000 3f49 a8d2 0000 03be ea80 8000  ....?I..........
0000820: 3f9e 06c8 0000 03dc e45c 8000 3f42 b58f  ?........\..?B..
0000830: 0000 044f a75c 8000 3eaf 70e8 0000 047a  ...O.\..>.p....z
0000840: c47c 8000 3f4d bf51 0000 04c7 89d0 8000  .|..?M.Q........
0000850: 3f60 f4c1 0000 04d0 357c 8000 3f65 98ae  ?`......5|..?e..
0000860: 0000 04d0 4160 8000 3f42 b58f 0000 0526  ....A`..?B.....&
0000870: 60e4 8000 3f22 8811 0000 059e 3ad8 8000  `...?"......:...
0000880: 3f4a 739a 0000 05dc 89d4 8000 3f5c 7fe4  ?Js.........?\..
0000890: 0000 064a 9860 8004 01c2 3f39 aa5b 0000  ...J.`....?9.[..
00008a0: 013e 808c 8000 3f16 1c3a 0000 0193 b070  .>....?..:.....p
00008b0: 8000 3f30 32d9 0000 01f5 0fc4 8000 3f30  ..?02.........?0
00008c0: 32d9 0000 01f5 1858 8000 3f50 214d 0000  2......X..?P!M..
00008d0: 024d e568 8000 3f4f 3d01 0000 0294 d3b8  .M.h..?O=.......
00008e0: 8000 3f50 b176 0000 02fa 8634 8000 3f44  ..?P.v.....4..?D
00008f0: ede8 0000 0617 11f8 8000 3fc3 8e99 0000  ..........?.....
0000900: 062b 5314 8005 0269 723f 536e a300 0001  .+S....ir?Sn....
0000910: 327f 6c80 003f 536e a300 0001 4184 3480  2.l..?Sn....A.4.
0000920: 003f 48a1 f900 0003 694d ec80 0501 6e3f  .?H.....iM....n?
0000930: 49a4 8e00 0002 950d a880 0505 7469 6f6e  I...........tion
0000940: 733f 4513 1e00 0000 f1a4 9080 0401 d03f  s?E............?
0000950: 39ce 2500 0002 bc91 b880 003f 536e a300  9.%........?Sn..
0000960: 0003 c657 d480 0401 65ff fff5 7c00 0000  ...W....e...|...
0000970: 7a7c 0080 0501 c23f 2b9a b800 0000 6222  z|.....?+.....b"
0000980: f880 003f 45fd a800 0002 9862 e880 003f  ...?E......b...?
0000990: 1d17 6500 0005 974f 4c80 003f 49a4 8e00  ..e....OL..?I...
00009a0: 0005 a0ce e080 003f 25f1 de00 0005 c6ff  .......?%.......
00009b0: d480 003e e5fb 4500 0005 fb7d e480 0602  ...>..E....}....
00009c0: 4952 3f63 40a7 0000 01fd 2428 8000 3f63  IR?c@.....$(..?c
00009d0: 40a7 0000 02c0 6ba4 8005 0463 7a6e 613f  @.....k....czna?
00009e0: 35c1 bc00 0004 1087 4c80 0501 643f 380a  5.......L...d?8.
00009f0: 4e00 0000 0b5f 4880 003f 41a5 6000 0000  N...._H..?A.`...
0000a00: 0f67 c080 003f 32e1 d300 0000 107e 9880  .g...?2......~..
0000a10: 003f 6340 a700 0000 4789 b880 003f 2d49  .?c@....G....?-I
0000a20: 0e00 0000 49b0 5c80 003f 1c8d 6200 0000  ....I.\..?..b...
0000a30: 4d8b f480 003f 4ede 9600 0000 512a 0c80  M....?N.....Q*..
0000a40: 003f 536e a300 0000 5703 6480 003f 5218  .?Sn....W.d..?R.
0000a50: f800 0000 574d 9080 003f 4513 1e00 0000  ....WM...?E.....
0000a60: 612c e880 003f 32e1 d300 0000 654a d880  a,...?2.....eJ..
0000a70: 003f 32e1 d300 0000 654a d880 003f 32e1  .?2.....eJ...?2.
0000a80: d300 0000 654a d880 003f 32e1 d300 0000  ....eJ...?2.....
0000a90: 654a d880 003f 32e1 d300 0000 654a d880  eJ...?2.....eJ..
0000aa0: 003f 32e1 d300 0000 654a d806 ba52 0000  .?2.....eJ...R..
0000ab0: 0586 d6bc 0006 ba53 0000 0586 da3c 0006  .......S.....<..
0000ac0: ba54 0000 0586 dc6c 0006 ba55 0000 0586  .T.....l...U....
0000ad0: de9c 0006 ba56 0000 0586 e1e4 0006 ba57  .....V.........W
0000ae0: 0000 0586 e674 0006 b9f2 0000 0585 c9f8  .....t..........
0000af0: 0006 b9f3 0000 0585 cc1c 0006 b9f4 0000  ................
0000b00: 0585 cd90 0006 b9f5 0000 0585 d0e0 0006  ................
0000b10: b9f6 0000 0585 d528 0006 b9f7 0000 0585  .......(........
0000b20: d888 0006 b9f8 0000 0585 ddb8 0006 b9f9  ................
0000b30: 0000 0585 e0d8 0006 b9fa 0000 0585 e3b8  ................
0000b40: 0006 b9fb 0000 0585 e654 0006 b9fc 0000  .........T......
0000b50: 0585 e7f4 0006 b9fd 0000 0585 ea40 0006  .............@..
0000b60: b9fe 0000 0585 ed28 0006 b9ff 0000 0585  .......(........
0000b70: ee34 0006 ba00 0000 0585 f008 0006 ba01  .4..............
0000b80: 0000 0585 f458 0006 ba02 0000 0585 f1ac  .....X..........
0000b90: 0006 ba03 0000 0585 f6a4 0006 ba04 0000  ................
0000ba0: 0585 fa10 0006 ba05 0000 0585 fda8 0006  ................
0000bb0: ba06 0000 0586 0120 0006 ba07 0000 0586  ....... ........
0000bc0: 03c8 0006 ba08 0000 0586 0614 0006 ba09  ................
0000bd0: 0000 0586 0808 0006 ba0a 0000 0586 0c34  ...............4
0000be0: 0006 ba0b 0000 0586 0e70 0006 ba0c 0000  .........p......
0000bf0: 0586 1138 0006 ba0d 0000 0586 12e8 53e8  ...8..........S.
0000c00: 0257 0006 6c61 7269 616d 3f4c 3b45 0000  .W..lariam?L;E..
0000c10: 02a1 d7ac 8000 3f6a 6ea7 0000 02a2 0484  ......?jn.......
0000c20: 8000 3f49 2891 0000 02b9 e8ec 8000 3f53  ..?I(.........?S
0000c30: 6ea3 0000 02c0 e35c 8000 3f53 6ea3 0000  n......\..?Sn...
0000c40: 02cf 5cc4 8000 3f4e 33c2 0000 02cf ee64  ..\...?N3......d
0000c50: 8000 3f58 375a 0000 02ec 36a8 8000 3f37  ..?X7Z....6...?7
0000c60: 90fb 0000 02f0 6ccc 8005 016e 3f56 22e7  ......l....n?V".
0000c70: 0000 038a afa8 8004 0263 613f 5766 5a00  .........ca?WfZ.
0000c80: 0004 06ac e480 060a 686f 6c69 6461 7969  ........holidayi
0000c90: 6e6e 3f65 98ae 0000 0123 d448 8000 3f65  nn?e.....#.H..?e
0000ca0: 98ae 0000 0124 dc60 8000 3f65 98ae 0000  .....$.`..?e....
0000cb0: 015f b478 8000 3f65 98ae 0000 020b 5024  ._.x..?e......P$
0000cc0: 8000 3f65 98ae 0000 0263 193c 8004 036d  ..?e.....c.<...m
0000cd0: 6172 3fa6 b715 0000 054b 31e0 8005 0265  ar?......K1....e
0000ce0: 723f 41a5 6000 0005 251f d880 003f 2aab  r?A.`...%....?*.
0000cf0: 0100 0005 9d31 b080 0402 6e61 3f3b 7e9d  .....1....na?;~.
0000d00: 0000 01bb fddc 8004 0273 613f 6ced 6700  .........sa?l.g.
0000d10: 0000 6c0a 9c80 0502 7361 3f45 131e 0000  ..l.....sa?E....
0000d20: 00d8 85e4 8004 0374 69d0 3f45 131e 0000  .......ti.?E....
0000d30: 02b0 35ac 8003 016b 3f4a b319 0000 0182  ..5....k?J......
0000d40: 4f40 8000 3f2c 5b14 0000 054e 9070 8000  O@..?,[....N.p..
0000d50: 3f41 7886 0000 05fc 9dd8 8004 0161 3f0f  ?Ax..........a?.
0000d60: 9c0c 0000 05d8 4730 8004 0665 6e72 6f73  ......G0...enros
0000d70: 653f 499b be00 0001 46de cc80 0401 693f  e?I.....F.....i?
0000d80: 0f9c 0c00 0005 d847 3080 0501 6e3f 60f4  .......G0...n?`.
0000d90: c100 0004 455a e880 003f 1fb4 3b00 0005  ....EZ...?..;...
0000da0: a259 a480 0405 7370 7572 733f ace5 a300  .Y....spurs?....
0000db0: 0005 cc10 3880 0303 6d65 733f 4ab3 1900  ....8...mes?J...
0000dc0: 0004 5726 e880 0406 6f79 616e 7473 3f37  ..W&....oyants?7
0000dd0: 37b5 0000 0374 81bc 8003 014e 3ef7 5668  7....t.....N>.Vh
0000de0: 0000 01a3 5454 8004 0361 6361 3f46 f9eb  ....TT...aca?F..
0000df0: 0000 00ae 5d74 8000 3f5e b49d 0000 0321  ....]t..?^.....!
0000e00: 3ce8 8003 056f 7573 7365 3f34 a48d 0000  <....ousse?4....
0000e10: 0541 fd74 8003 0150 3f2a 1fff 0000 0284  .A.t...P?*......
0000e20: b01c 8004 0153 3f4a b319 0000 010c d6c8  .....S?J........
0000e30: 8003 0272 793f 54ab f200 0000 07a4 d480  ...ry?T.........
0000e40: 003f 45fd a800 0000 478b 3c80 003f 3dab  .?E.....G.<..?=.
0000e50: cf00 0000 4a7f 0c00 0000 478b 3c80 003f  ....J.....G.<..?
0000e60: 3dab cf00 0000 4a7f 0c80 003f 3dab cf00  =.....J....?=...
0000e70: 0000 4a7f 0c86 c53c 0006 ba4d 0000 0586  ..J....<...M....
0000e80: c858 0006 ba4e 0000 0586 cad4 0006 ba4f  .X...N.........O
0000e90: 0000 0586 cf08 0006 ba50 0000 0586 d240  .........P.....@
0000ea0: 0006 ba51 0000 0586 d48c 0006 ba52 0000  ...Q.........R..
0000eb0: 0586 d6bc 0006 ba53 0000 0586 da3c 0006  .......S.....<..
0000ec0: ba54 0000 0586 dc6c 0006 ba55 0000 0586  .T.....l...U....
0000ed0: de9c 0006 ba56 0000 0586 e1e4 0006 ba57  .....V.........W
0000ee0: 0000 0586 e674 0006 ba58 0000 0586 e98c  .....t...X......
0000ef0: 0006 ba59 0000 0586 ecbc 0006 ba5a 0000  ...Y.........Z..
0000f00: 0586 efbc 0006 ba5b 0000 0586 f26c 0006  .......[.....l..
0000f10: b9f6 0000 0585 d528 0006 b9f7 0000 0585  .......(........
0000f20: d888 0006 b9f8 0000 0585 ddb8 0006 b9f9  ................
0000f30: 0000 0585 e0d8 0006 b9fa 0000 0585 e3b8  ................
0000f40: 0006 b9fb 0000 0585 e654 0006 b9fc 0000  .........T......
0000f50: 0585 e7f4 0006 b9fd 0000 0585 ea40 0006  .............@..
0000f60: b9fe 0000 0585 ed28 0006 b9ff 0000 0585  .......(........
0000f70: ee34 0006 ba00 0000 0585 f008 0006 ba01  .4..............
0000f80: 0000 0585 f458 0006 ba02 0000 0585 f1ac  .....X..........
0000f90: 0006 ba03 0000 0585 f6a4 0006 ba04 0000  ................
0000fa0: 0585 fa10 0006 ba05 0000 0585 fda8 0006  ................
0000fb0: ba06 0000 0586 0120 0006 ba07 0000 0586  ....... ........
0000fc0: 03c8 0006 ba08 0000 0586 0614 0006 ba09  ................
0000fd0: 0000 0586 0808 0006 ba0a 0000 0586 0c34  ...............4
0000fe0: 0006 ba0b 0000 0586 0e70 0006 ba0c 0000  .........p......
0000ff0: 0586 1138 0006 ba0d 0000 0586 12e8 53e8  ...8..........S.
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you're going to be able to track down a root cause. I threw the data into a disassembler and can say reasonably confidently that it isn't x86/x64 machine language, so I sincerely doubt it was any attempt by malware to make itself persistent across reboots. It looks, to me, like an in-memory data from an application (possibly just some random heap garbage) that was erroneously written to the MBR of the disk. I'd suspect that there's some dodgy hardware components involved that are operating close to their tolerances and some bits got flipped. I've seen enough randomly overwritten MBRs over the years (albeit mainly in the more distant past, when hardware was dodgier and RAM wasn't typically ECC) that I'd be willing to chalk this up to gremlins.